# Centos Service started but remains disabled

Tags: docker, unix, service, centos, systemctl

I downloaded Docker for my Centos server. After installing via yum and started the service with `systemctl start docker` I noticed an incoherent situation.

The service is running:

```sh
$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-01-16 11:19:57 UTC; 1min 16s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1691 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 39
   Memory: 37.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─1691 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

but remains in disabled state:

```sh
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep docker
docker.service                                disabled
docker.socket                                 disabled
```

Why does it happen? Can a disabled service be running?

Comment: disable mean that the service will not run when the server restart, issue `systemctl enable docker` to make it enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/733469/what-is-the-difference-between-systemctl-start-and-systemctl-enable), `systemctl enable` makes the service to be active as long as the server is running and `systemctl start` makes it run now.

If we run the service while it is in `disabled` state, it means when the server reboots the service will not run automatically. But being in `disabled` state does not prevent it to run!